# How to display calendar events in a one day calendar view with perticular time slots on Android?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-calendar

I have been looking around and have been trying to figure out how this was possible, but no such luck. How exactly can I line up an event in a correct position in a list view for events in a day down to, lets say, minutes rather than just 30 minute intervals?

Can anyone direct me to example code of this, as I have had no such luck finding it, or just explaining how this may be possible. I also might as well ask, but is the `MonthDisplayHelper` class the only helper to display a calendar? I was just curious if there was another. I really appreciate the time anyone takes to answer this.

What I mean by intervals,

> 3:00 3:30 4:00 etc.

and a visual representation of this is here: [image]

Comment: I have the same task, isn't there any common way, using google calendar or so on? Or I should create it custom ?

Comment: You have to create a custom one. But there are open source options @Nininea. I'm partial to creating my own. Or steal the one from the google calendar source. Up to you. Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

First of all you have to create day view using grid view filled by textview. And after creating layout you easily find position of every row. You can easily put and fetch events using time and position of grid view.

Comment: Whats second of all? Lol, but I appreciate the advice. I did not think to use grid layout on that. But how would the layout be filled in? Could you give me an example please. Like I assume each hour has a grid... maybe? I am just not sure what you mean. But if yes, then how can you fill in say an event thats like 4 hours long and make it look as one event on the screen?

Answer (score 2):

I was going through the [IOSHED](http://code.google.com/r/peppingmarkus-ioshed/) app. It has a module called **schedule**  which is same as per your requirement.

Check out [this](http://code.google.com/r/peppingmarkus-ioshed/source/browse/android/res/layout/fragment_schedule.xml?r=becd6bc6c4d19a716efb92175e887bfaa9626553) layout. and ultimately this results as

[image]

Hope it helps.